# NetBeans code coverage without changing POM

Tags: netbeans, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I can very easily get a code coverage report in NetBeans, but adding the following to my project `pom.xml`:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, the rest of my team would prefer not to have the JaCoCo dependency  into the project source repository. They get IDE code coverage from EclEMMA in Eclipse, and there are other systems in the CI chain that do code quality checks.

My best solution at the moment is to copy/paste the JaCoCo plugin stanza into the POM when working locally, then remove it before committing to SCM. Is there a better way to see coverage in NetBeans without editing the POM?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution, but if you have a ***good SCM*** like **Git** or **Mercurial** you can use a **local (= private) *"coverage branch"*** with Jacoco added.

If some work is ready to check, switch to that branch, merge / rebase with your development branch and run jacoco. That way you can get back to the clean pom at any time and you don't have that annoying manual copy & paste work. The dev branch wont contain your changes at any time, plus you can't commit it by accident.

It's also possible to work on the coverage branch and merge commits back to the dev one.

---

Ps. If you are using eg. *SVN* or *CVS* you are possible lost that way …

Comment: We use git, so this is a possibility. Thanks.